# Masking camera preview on a TextureView

Tags: android, camera, preview, masking, textureview

I'm using a TextureView to show the camera preview. For project needs it should be square and with rounded corners. This is working fine for the square part, as I can use the transformation Matrix to readjust the ratio deformation, but I have no clue on how to mask the video with rounded corners.

Basically what I've found is:

1. As the TextureView is showing the camera preview, I cant' lock the canvas to modify it.
2. I can't override onDraw as it's declared final in the TextureView class (it makes quite sense)

Is there any way to process the camera output out of the transformation Matrix?

Comment: If you sent the camera preview to a SurfaceTexture, you can treat the frame like a texture and use GLES to do whatever you want to with it (see e.g. Grafika's "texture from camera" activity).  What might be easier is to define an overlapping custom View with a transparent background, draw the "rounded" effect on it, and place it in front of the TextureView.

Comment: The problem is that background is an image and i was expecting to avoid open gl, but it looks like the only solution.

Comment: The down side of GLES is that it's complicated.  The up side is that you can do pretty amazing things.

Comment: Every magic comes with a price :)